# Using Rolify in conjunction with (or in place of) join tables for many-to-many relationships

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, database-design, associations, rolify

I'm trying to figure out the best way to design some of the db relationships for my application. I have a number of relationships that are many-to-many. Here is an example of one such relationship:

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :groups_users
  has_many :groups, through: :groups_users
end

class Group < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :groups_users
  has_many :groups, through: :groups_users
end

class GroupsUser < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :group
  belongs_to :user
end
```

So this will allow me to define what users belong to what groups. However, I also need to know what their access level to a group is. So in the groups_users table I have extra attributes, like admin, contributor, etc. If I wanted to make a user the admin of a group, I'd do something like

```
u = User.find(34)
g = Group.find(22)
gu = u.groups_users.where(:group => g).first
gu.update(admin: true)
```

This whole setup works fine but I've been looking into using Rolify and it seems like it could be applicable in this situation. Rolify allows me to set a user's role for an instance of a class, so to do the above I would do this:

```
u = User.find(34)
g = Group.find(22)
u.add_role(:admin, g)
```

I like the idea of Rolify so I figured I could do this and get rid of the extra attributes in the join table. But now I'm feeling like I'm kinda mixing and matching since I'm using the join table to get what groups a user has (`u.groups`) but then I need to use Rolify to get their access level for each group somehow. Maybe that's the way to do it... but it occurred to me that I could just use Rolify and get rid of the join tables altogether. I just add a "base" role so to speak, like :member. So instead of using `u.groups` to get a users groups I would do `Group.with_role(:member, u)`. I wouldn't have the ability to do stuff like `u.groups = [g1, g2, g3]` but I was already going to have to mess with that a bit in order to set the users access levels for each group.

So I guess I'm just looking for recommendations as to how to do this. I have a number of many-to-many relationships involving users and I like the idea of using Rolify to handle all of that so I don't have a bunch of join tables and classes, but as someone who is new to Rolify (and not an expert in this stuff to begin with) I'm not sure if I'm missing some pitfalls with this approach.

Answer (score 0):

Rolify allows you scoped roles as shown in the following code. I have copied it from Rolify wiki.

```
user = User.find(2)
user.add_role :moderator, Forum.first # sets a role scoped to a resource instance
user.has_role? :moderator, Forum.first
=> true
user.has_role? :moderator, Forum.last
=> false
```

You can consider adding a `scoped role` in `user_groups` for the given user. For example, `user_a`' will have role `admin` limited to `group_a`.

```
user_a = User.create(name: 'user a')
group_a = Group.create(name: 'group a')
group_a.users << user_a
user.add_role :admin, UserGroup.first
```